# Displaying each element of a varying sized list one at a time

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to take a user's input, which will determine as list of results.  I would like to show that list to the user, one result at a time.  Something like the following (which is broken):

```
Panel[Column[{
   Row[{"How many squares? ", InputField[Dynamic[x], Number]}],
   (*m=1 so that no out of range error for x < m:*)
   Row[{ButtonBox["Squares!", Evaluator -> Automatic, 
       ButtonFunction -> (m = 1; (r = Map[#^2 &, Range[x]]) &), 
       Appearance -> "DialogBox"] // DisplayForm}],
   Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[m], Dynamic[Length[r]]]}],
   Row[{r[[m]]}]
   }]]
```

It seems that the trouble I am running into is setter bar not taking a dynamic range.  I also tried using previous and next buttons which would increment or decrement x modulo m, but Mod[m,x] wasn't happy with a dynamic argument either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, `Length[r]` will be an integer which will not work as a second argument of a `SetterBar`. Moreover `Dynamic` head stays there so something like `Dynamic @ Range @ Length @ r` will not be recognized as a `List` correctly. You have to move that `Dynamic` outside the `Setterbar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[Row[{SetterBar[Dynamic[y], Range[x]], Dynamic[y]}], 
 {{x, 1,"Squares"}, InputField[#, Number] &}]
```

[image]